# RabbitMQ installation fails on path that includes parentheses

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a problem when installing RabbitMQ (3.7.14) with a path that includes parentheses.

for example:

```
C:\Program Files (ABC)\RabbitMQ Server

F:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server
```

One exception: `C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server`

The failure occurs in: rabbitmq-env.bat during the installation, when trying to set variable with value of `%~dps1`.

`C:\Program Files (x86)\RabbitMQ Server` is OK because `C:\Program Files (x86)` has a short name that replaces the parentheses when reading `%~dps1`.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recently fixed this and it will ship with RabbitMQ `3.7.18`. We have a [`3.7.18` release beta](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/releases/tag/v3.7.18-beta.1) available.